Docker error: Docker starts with https://localhost:0/swagger
I'm trying to run a .Net 8 application with this Dockerfile:
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:9000
EXPOSE 9000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["EPS.Gateway/EPS.Gateway.csproj", "EPS.Gateway/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./EPS.Gateway/EPS.Gateway.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/EPS.Gateway"
RUN dotnet build "./EPS.Gateway.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./EPS.Gateway.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EPS.Gateway.dll", "--server.urls", "http://+:9000"]

I'm running it from Visual Studio 2022, but it doesn't run on http://localhost:9000/swagger/index.html as expected and get redirected to https://localhost:0/swagger
Its log says it's listening on port 9000:
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:9000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:9000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app

I tried every ways I saw on Stackoverflow but it didn't work.

show command , how to run docker command.

@life888888 I run it directly from Visual Studio, from the panel right next to the Startup Project.

Visual Studio sets a lot of parameters on the docker run command that it runs for you when it starts the container and that affects how the container runs. Can you, somewhere in Visual Studio, see the command it runs?

I only had this problem. In my case i had wrong ports in my enviroments variebles. Make sure you have correct ports in DockerFile, docker-compose.yml and in enviroments variebles

Thank you. I found it yesterday, it's in the launchSettings.json file where I set the httpPort and the sslPort.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
